# cannot read data from database file in asset folder

Tags: android, database, sqlite, external

I am trying to get login information from users and then check the database to find the information and if the information exist in the database the program leads the user to another page otherwise it toast that "wrong information". But I found that android cannot read information from the user table form database. I have to mention that the database folder will create in data folder and I can see my database file in this folder. please help me to solve my problem. here is all the codes i have written:
ExternalDataBase class:

```
public class ExternalDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private String db_path = null;
private static String db_name = "testdb.db";
public static final String tbl_user = "Tbl_Users";
public static final String tbl_product = "Tbl_Product";
//TABLE_CONTENT

private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private final Context context;

/*
constructor taks and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
access to the application assets and resources.
*/

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public ExternalDataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, db_name, null, 1);
    this.context = context;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        db_path = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        Toast.makeText(context, "ana", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        db_path = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        Toast.makeText(context, "arta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

/* Create a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database */

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        //do nothing, database is already exist
    } else {

        /* By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path.
        of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.*/

        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {

        String myPath = db_path + db_name;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY
                | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS
                | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);


    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        //database doesn't exist yet
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}
/* copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the system
 * folder, from where it can be accessed and handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.*/

public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(db_name);
    //path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = db_path + db_name;
    //open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    //transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    // open the database
    String myPath = db_path + db_name;
    //SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZAED_COLLATORS
    sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY
            | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS
            | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (sqLiteDatabase != null)
        sqLiteDatabase.close();

    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

UserAdapter.java class:

```
public class UserDbAdapter extends ExternalDataBase {

public static String KEY_ID = "id";
public static String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

/* Constructor take and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access
* to the application assets and resources.*/

public UserDbAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public long Insert(Users users) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, users.getUsername());
    contentValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, users.getPassword());

    return db.insertOrThrow(tbl_user, null, contentValues);
}

public int Login(Users users) {
    int res = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from "+tbl_user+" where "+KEY_USERNAME +"='"+users.getUsername()+"' and "+
            " "+KEY_PASSWORD+"='"+users.getPassword()+"' ",null);
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        res = 1;
    } else {
        res = 0;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;

}
```

}

Users Class:

```
public class Users  {

private int Id;
private String Username;
private String Password;


public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    Id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return Username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    Username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    Password = password;
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ExternalDataBase externalDatabase;
UserDbAdapter userDbAdapter;
EditText txt_username,txt_password;
Button btn_enter;
public int result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt_username = findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
    txt_password = findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
    btn_enter = findViewById(R.id.btn_enter);

    externalDatabase = new ExternalDataBase(getApplicationContext());

    LoadingDatabase();

    userDbAdapter = new UserDbAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    btn_enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        String username = txt_username.getText().toString();
        String password = txt_password.getText().toString();

        Users users = new Users();
        users.setPassword(username);
        users.setUsername(password);

        result = userDbAdapter.Login(users);

        if(result == 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong information",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
    });
    }

private void LoadingDatabase() {
    try{
        externalDatabase.createDataBase();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    externalDatabase.openDataBase();
}

}
```

Comment: no userDbAdapter codes

Comment: where is userDbAdapter code?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I corrected it.